# how to prove that $x^2 + y^2 =1$ is injective and surjective depending on the restrictions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

Suppose we have 
$S=\{(x,y) \in [-1,1]\times[0,1]: x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$

I know this is a function since the domain(s)= $[-1,1]$ and I know this should be surjective and injective since the restriction makes the image out to be a top half circle, but I am having trouble proving that this function is a injective and onto function.

For injective I am usually working with just $X$ variables for example if I want to prove that 
$x+3$ is injective  for all real numbers then I just let $x+3=y+3$ and calculate $x=y$ since the definition of injective is if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x=y$ but i get stumped with this equation of the circle.

Should I just set $x^2 + y^2 =1$ to $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and set
$\sqrt{1-x^2} = \sqrt{1-y^2}$?

Comment: Yes, this relation makes $y$ a function of $x$, but what makes you think the function is injective?

Comment: oh i see, what you are saying. it shouldnt be one to one actually since there are y values paired with more than one x value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be much more careful with your function/relation.

The set of points satisfying $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is a relation; in order to say something is injective or surjective, you must be very precise specifying the domain, the range, and in particular, you need a function.

If it's the top half of a circle, the equation $f(x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2} : [-1, 1] \to [0, 1]$ will work, but the reason you have a function is **not** because the domain is $x \in [-1, 1]$.

At any rate, you're going to have a hard time showing that distinct $x$'s get sent to distinct $y$'s; that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ implies $x_1 = x_2$. Think geometrically.

Comment: such as the vertical line test

Comment: i see, so this function should actually be surjective and not injective

Comment: Right! And the reason you even have a function is that we're restricting $y \in [0, 1]$, and not the full $[-1, 1]$. Because if we're solving the equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, we have two possibilities; $y = \pm \sqrt{1 - x^2}$. We could choose either the positive or the negative, but we must choose one, in order to have a function (since $x$ can only get mapped to one $y$. This is another reason why it's important to specify the function: We could just as well have solved for $x = \pm \sqrt{1 - y^2}$, with domain $y \in [0, 1]$, in which case we wouldn't even have a function.

Answer (score 1):

An injective mapping $f$ would satisfy the property that if $f(a) = f(b)$, then $a = b$.  This is obviously not the case for your mapping, defined by $$y = \sqrt{1-x^2},$$ where $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is the nonnegative square root.  For if $y = 3/5$, then $x^2 = 1 - (3/5)^2 = (4/5)^2$, hence $x = \pm 4/5$.  The mapping thus admits a case where $a \ne b$ but $f(a) = f(b)$, contradiction.

Surjectivity, however, is a property of the specification of the codomain:  it is implied by the definition of $S$ that your mapping is $$f : [-1,1] \to [0,1],$$ hence the codomain is $[0,1]$.  This does satisfy surjectivity:  if $y \in [0,1]$, there is at least one $x \in [-1,1]$ such that $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.  To see this, we observe that $x = \sqrt{1-y^2}$, so that $0 \le y \le 1$ implies $0 \ge -y^2 \ge -1$ and $1 \ge 1-y^2 \ge 0$.  Then taking the square root (either sign works), we are guaranteed to find such an $x \in [-1,1]$.

Had the codomain been, say, $[0,\infty)$, then this would fail to be a surjective map, since $y = 2$ has no preimage in $[-1,1]$.